# Add a StoryBoard to Galasoft's EventToCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm trying to add a storyboard to an event trigger, the event trigger is using Galasoft which I think is the reason this may not be working as intended.

I have a DataGrid, when I double click a row I would like to trigger an animation on the width of a grid column.

Below is my XAML DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" RowHeaderWidth="0" RowHeight="22" ItemsSource="{Binding SquirrelData}" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Name="dtSearch" Margin="10,5,10,10" ColumnWidth="*" Grid.Row="4" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenDetail}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
```

I cannot add   `<BeginStoryboard>` after the even trigger as the event trigger isn't the default Event trigger.

Any suggestions on how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are 2 approaches to fix your problem:**

- use `ControlStoryboardAction` inside `i:Interaction.Triggers`
- do not use `i:Interaction.Triggers` but regular triggers **(the one commented out)**

Code:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="88.314"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <!--<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
        </EventTrigger>-->
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104.234,113.568,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Pro tip:** Use Blend for Visual Studio to easily create such code using mouse instead.